# How can I make a Custom Control automatically apply a style defined in a resource dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, resourcedictionary

I have a control library with a custom control :

```
public class GlassButton : Button {
}
```

and I have also defined a resource dictionary to style the control :

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:Animations="clr-namespace:WPFTools.Classes"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WPFTools.Controls"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:GlassButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

I want to be able to simply drag and drop the `GlassButton` onto a window or control and **NOT** have to do this :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Foo"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I've been able to do this once before but that knowledge seems to have been lost to me.

How can I make this happen? ( I'm fine making changes in the code behind of my control ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to re-remember how this worked a week ago, and this is what I had to do to make it work for me. The typical way with custom controls is to define the style in a file named `generic.xaml` located in the `Themes` folder directly beneath your project root. Then you need to override the default style in the static constructor of your custom control class. It would look something like this:

```
public class GlassButton : Button
{
    static GlassButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof( GlassButton ),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( typeof( GlassButton ) ) );
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to set the appropriate assembly property to say that your generic theme is located within your assembly. Something like this would go in your `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
using System.Windows;
[assembly:ThemeInfo( ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly )]
```

I'm not sure if this is strictly necessary, but I also had to change the Build Action property on my `generic.xaml` file to Page before the default style would get properly applied to my control.

Comment: This is about right, yes; although I was really hoping to avoid having to separate the XAML from the CS file... Maybe there is a way but this is definitely what I had done before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for this work is creation DictionaryResources contains your all WPF Styles in application for every app style you want.
[image]

So you can remove your current style and add new style dynamically like below:[image]